# What's the first words of the opening?

Tags: atelier-rorona

There's a translation of the opening video [online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UP5Ev_eYRYY), but it doesn't translate whatever's being chanted during the first few seconds.

Does it even have meaning?